# Include multiple (wildcard) URIs, exclude subdomains in regular expression

Tags: php, regex, wildcard

Hope you can help me out with formatting the correct RegEx.

I want to:

---

1) Include all traffic to domain.com(.*)

- EXCLUDING all subdomains
- EXCEPT all traffic to the specific URI sub.domain.com/folder(.*)

2) Include all traffic to the specific URI sub.extdomain.com/folder(.*)

**Some examples:**

Include:

- domain.com
- domain.com/team
- domain.com/blog
- Specific: hello.domain.com/bonjour
- Specific: bye.extdomain.com/aurevoir/salut

Exclude:

- hello.domain.com
- bye.domain.com
- All other subdomains & other sites

---

Already tried the following, but it still includes subdomains:

```
(domain\.com|sub\.domain\.com/folder(.*)|sub\.domain\.com/folder(.*))
```

Comment: Can you provide some sample inputs?

Comment: Done! Hope you can help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The regex  `/domain\.com/`  will match any subdomain because it will match part of the string.
use  `/^domain\.com/`  to catch only strings beginning with "domain.com"  (no sub domain).

Note this assumes you removed the protocol from the url (http://).

The 2nd part of the RegEx you posted is the same as the 3rd part - I assume you mean the two special cases - they too need the "^" beginning

No need for the (.*) at the end - it will match part of the string the all the same without it.

`(^domain\.com|^hello\.domain\.com\/bonjur|\^bye.extdomain\.com\/folder(.*))`

explanation - accept

- `^domain\.com` - all urls beginning with "domain.com"  (no subdomain)
- or `^hello\.domain.com` - all urls beginning with subdomain  "hello.domain.com"
- or `\^bye.extdomain\.com` - all urls beginning with "bye.extdomain.com"

optionally - because all 3 components start the same way you can extract the common prefix `^`:

`^(domain\.com|hello\.domain\.com\/bonjur|bye\.extdomain\.com\/folder2)`

See this website for help reading the regex: http://www.regexper.com/#%5E(domain%5C.com%7Chello%5C.domain%5C.com%5C%2Fbonjur%7Cbye%5C.extdomain%5C.com%5C%2Ffolder2)

Comment: Great, also smart to extract the ^ prefix. It works, awesome thx!

Answer (score 0):

I added a "^" to the start of the regex to require that the string begins with domain.com.
In the second clause it allows for folders following domain.com.
Third clause allows for anything on a sub domain, if it has a "/" followed by some text.

```
(^domain\.com$|^domain\.com\/\w*|\w*\.domain\.com\/\w*)
```

Comment: Thanks! Do I also need to add (.*) after ^domain\.com? (^domain\.com(.*)|sub\.domain\.com\/folder(.*)|sub\.domain\.com\/folder(.*))

Comment: Also, while testing this RegEx on http://regexpal.com, only "domain.com" is a match, all others not?

Comment: Yeah, I edited my answer to include the updated expression. It should now allow for the domain, as well as folders proceeding the domain.

Comment: This code does not really do what I'm looking for, as I only want to include a specific subdomain for the main domain, and a specific subdomain for an external domain. No wildcards! :)

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using this regex:

```
'#\b(?:domain\.com|hello\.domain\.com/bonjour|bye\.extdomain\.com/aurevoir/salut)\b#i'
```

Comment: Ok ok, what does the '#\b(?: part do? Can't really find this in RegEx docs!

Comment: `#` is just a regex delimiter to avoid escaping `/` in the actual regex. `\b` is word boundary and `?:` is non capturing group.